# How do Vorpal weapons and Guild Executioners' Assassin's Action interact?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, weapons

With assassin's action and vorpal weapons that have xd4 damage dice, would the rolls of 1, 2 or 3 that become 4 damage get rerolled via the vorpal property?

Assassin's Action:

> when you spend an action point to make an attack, and you roll a 1, 2
>   or 3 on any damage die associated with that attack (including extra
>   damage from assassin's strike or critical hit dice), that die instead
>   deals 4 damage.

Vorpal weapon:

> Whenever you roll the maximum result on any damage die for this
>   weapon, roll that die again and add the additional result to the
>   damage total. If a reroll results in another maximum damage result,
>   roll it again and keep adding.

Answer (score 13):

**Assassin's Action does not trigger Vorpal.**

Let's look at the wording in Assassin's Action (emphasis mine)...

> When... you roll a 1, 2 or 3 on any damage die ... that die *instead deals 4 damage*.

...and in Vorpal weapon (emphasis again mine):

> Whenever you *roll the maximum result* on any damage die for this weapon...

Assassin's Action doesn't treat the die as a 4, nor does it let your re-roll until you get a 4. It just says if you roll less than a 4 on a damage die you deal 4 damage instead of whatever you rolled. Vorpal weapon is explicitly triggered by getting the maximum value *on the die*; it doesn't care how much *damage* the die dealt, it cares about the actual number that was rolled, which Assassin's Action doesn't affect.

Assassin's Action gets you bonus damage when you roll less than a 4, and Vorpal weapon gets you another die when you roll a 4 (on a 1d4), but no single die can benefit from both effects.

After the first time people found a way to deal infinite damage with Vorpal weapon (Battle Engineers could originally give a weapon brutal 1, or increase its brutal rating by 1 if it was already brutal), that method was promptly errata-ed and WotC was pretty careful from then on about not adding any other ways to guarantee you always got a 4 on d4 damage dice.